# How do you change what a function in a core module does?

Tags: hooks

I am trying to change certain Drupal behavior. I have traced this behavior back to a function in RDF core module, and would like to change what it does. The function in question is [`rdf_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!rdf!rdf.module/function/rdf_preprocess_node/7).

Getting what I want would seem as simple as removing one or two blocks of code from this function. So that's exactly what I tried doing: I copied the function into my theme's template.php, made the changes, renamed the function from `rdf_preprocess_node` to `THEMENAME_rdf_preprocess_node`. This did not work, Devel Themer did not list my `THEMENAME_rdf_preprocess_node` among the preprocess functions used.

I do not understand why this didn't work. Only other option that I know is to try and dig through what the function affected and undo it, which sounds horrible.

*What's a practical way to change what a function from another module does?*

Comment: `rdf_preprocess_node()` is just an implementation of `hook_preprocess_node` - `rdf_preprocess_node()` itself is not a hook.

Comment: @ayesh, to be clear, does that imply that `rdf_preprocess_node()` cannot be overriden from another module/theme, and I have to implement my own `hook_preprocess_node` and undo changes made by `rdf_preprocess_node()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy.

All you have to do is implement your own [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).  Then inside, it update the `$variables` that the RDF module made.  If you want to update the header additions that it did, then implement a [`hook_html_head_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7), and update those elements.

If you do this from your theme, then these will run after the RDF module.  If you do it from a module, then you need to set the weight to be higher than the RDF module.